# Application does not support IE9. Any way I can notify my IE9 users through javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

Unfortunately our webmail client delivered from Oracle is not compliant with the new IE9.

Does anyone know of a smart way I can modify for example the login page to notify any IE9 users that it is not compliant?

Comment: Do you have access to the HTML source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually approaching this the entirely wrong way.

Instead of forcing users not to use IE9, force IE9 to behave like IE8 (or IE7) by using setting the compatibility mode.

Throw this into the header (or into the http-headers);

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

and it will behave as IE8.

You can read more about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should parse the user-agent string as described [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
The example check version 8, but should be the same for Version 9.

You could also use something like

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<p>My message for IE9 & above users</p>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Using UA sniffing is a very slippery slope. You should be using feature detection instead.

Comment: UA Sniffing is bad, but IEs conditional comments are a relatively clean feature that can be safely used to target IE versions 5-9, and that's what is shown here.